# React Map function iterates through an array only once

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an image input tag which is multiple. I want each image to be scaled down. I use the map function for this. I call this within a useEffect function. But now it is the case that the map function is only run through once, no matter how many images are in an array. How can I change this ?

```
const articelImg = (e) => {
if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
  setFiles([...files, e.target.files]);
}
};

useEffect(() => {
files.length &&
  files.map(async (file, idx) => { //Two objects, but only interred once
    const thump = await thumpnail(file[idx]);
    setThumpnails([...thumpnails, thump]);
  });
}, [files]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

when you are working with async/await code in a loop best approach is to use for of loop, below is the code you can give it a try

```
const articelImg = (e) => {
  if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
    setFiles([...files, e.target.files]);
  }
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => if (files.length) {
      for await (let file of files){
        const thump = await thumpnail(file[idx]);
        setThumpnails([...thumpnails, thump]);
      }
    })()
    
  }, [files]);
```

Comment: Thx, but dosen't take effect

Comment: are you getting any error, or facing issue related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably got a stale state in this line `setThumpnails([...thumpnails, thump]);` because of async settings. Try this one `setThumpnails(thumpnails => [...thumpnails, thump]);` this will provide you a latest snapshot of state
or use refs as described in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function).